# Is this a case of the sequence of tenses?

Tags: past-tense

Are the bold words in the past tense due to the sequence of tenses?

> Those hypothetical scenarios don’t seem all that far-fetched. Kerry seemed to view those boots as dangerous magic shoes: they **had** the power to transform this into a military conflict that **mattered** to the American people; in their absence, there should be no cause for alarm, no real war with just missiles and planes.

---

Source:
http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/closeread/2013/09/john-kerry-syria-intervention-air-strike-moral-argument.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is extremely basic and is therefore better suited to [ell.se]

Comment: You have [now](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125277/what-does-last-check-here-mean#comment258459_125277) gone back and accepted some of the answers you have received for which I thank you. However, as I and quite a few others have now repeatedly pointed out to you, this sort of basic question is off topic here and should instead be taken to  English Language Learners. Why do you insist on posting these questions here?

Comment: I m sorry. I wasn't aware of that site, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is yes, these words are in the past tense because a '*completed action*' is shown to us

> *subordinate clause*: **they had the power to** transform this into a military conflict...

and main clause is in the past tense.